# Python - How do I split an array into multiple arrays after the first array reaches 1900 characters?

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have the variable `finalmessage` and if it exceeds 1900 characters I need to split it. I tried defining chunks, but nothing worked. I'm also using `discord.py`. [The relevant code is attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJzII.png)

Here is the code as text:

```
@client.command(name="draw", brief="Use W and B to draw, use period to go to the next line")
async def draw(ctx, drawmessage: str):
    drawfinalmessage = []
    messagelen = 0

    for char in drawmessage:
        if char == "B":
            drawfinalmessage.append(str(B))
        elif char == "W":
            drawfinalmessage.append(str(W))
        elif char == "R":
            drawfinalmessage.append(str(R))
        elif char == ".":
            drawfinalmessage.append("\n")
    finalmessage = ''.join(drawfinalmessage)
    if len(finalmessage) <= 2000:
        await ctx.send(finalmessage)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Message too long. It has to be ~100 characters or less.\nBecause Discord Emojis vary in string sizes, it may be more or less than 100.")
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question as text. It makes it easier for others to try out your code and to help you.

Comment: Okay, I will do that!

Comment: Why is it ok to send up to 2000 characters but the alternate message says that approx 100 is the limit? What size do you want the split message to be? Also, what are variables `B`, `W` and `R`?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the general idea:

```
test = ['g', 'g', 's', 'r', 't', 'a', 'a', 'b']
new_list = []
blank = []
limit = 3

for index, letter in enumerate(test):
    if not (index + 1) % limit:
        blank.append(letter)
        new_list.append(blank)
        blank = []
    elif index + 1 == len(test):
        blank.append(letter)
        new_list.append(blank)
        blank = []
    else:
        blank.append(letter)
```

Obviously I renamed the variables you are using, but essentially just swap out what you need (i.e. your limit should be 1900, test is your drawfinalmessage)

Comment: My code just breaks up your entire "drawfinalmessage" list into separate lists with the length of the "limit". You still have to loop through each of those separate lists and join them.

Comment: Any luck with that?